# Google Maps v3 API Extend Bounds. Javascript How-To?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

```
function initialize(){
// Creating a map
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  zoom: 10,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(53.0123601276819, -2.44519164333635),
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});

var m = [];

function addMarker(title, lat, lng) {
    m[m.length] = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
        map: map,
        title: title,  
        clickable: true,
        icon: 'http://domain.com/MVC/images/full.png' 
    });

} 

addMarker('Home', 53.0682143712504, -2.52150736731894);
addMarker('Away', 53.0123601276819, -2.44519164333635);
addMarker('Away', 59.0123601276819, -2.44519164333635);    

// Create a LatLngBounds object
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(); 

for (var i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {
  // Insert code to add marker to map here

  // Extend the LatLngBound object
  bounds.extend(m[i]);

}
alert(m[0]);
map.fitBounds(bounds);
  document.write(getBounds());   

}
```

The above is my code.

My intentions are to develop a map which shows numerous markers and pans the zoom such that all the markers fit on my screen.

I am new to JS.

My understanding is that

```
var m = [];
```

creates an empty array.

Then everytime i call `addMarker()` the details get added to this array m

At the top I set a default zoom and center point.

I then add various markers.

I then loop through each key in the m array and extend the bounds using the data from this.

It is then my understanding that `map.fitBounds(bounds);` should redefine the zoom/center as applicable to fit all the markers.

It does not.
All my markers show, but the zoom/center is not auto adjusting as such, and I have no idea why.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 11):

You need to pass a `LatLng` object to the `bounds.extend` function.

Here is the code :

```
....
bounds.extend(new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng));
....
```

Comment: That doesn't work for me.  Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Array] has no method 'lat'

Answer (score 6):

Here is a clarification of the above answer which is correct except it's missing a parenthesis and a little brief.

```
//make an empty bounds variable
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();


//do your map stuff here
//special note: make sure your lat and lng are floats or googleMaps will error
var lat = 38.103;
var lng = -121.572;
bounds.extend(new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng));


//adjust the viewport of the map
//special note: this only needs to be done once, don't put it in a loop
map.fitBounds(bounds);
```