# GoogleMaps: map not extending bounds to view all markers

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I'm having a problem.  I have an array of locations of our dealers.  It's called `locations`.  The first item in each group is the latitude and the last item in each group is the longitude. I get back a map with all of the locations on it correctly, except it zooms in on one of the locations.  It has to be something with the bounds, but I'm not sure what.  Can someone help?  Thanks.

Here's my code:

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });

var marker, i;

if (locations.length > 1) { 
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][0], locations[i][1]),
                    map: map
                });
    }

    bounds.extend(marker.getPosition());              

    map.fitBounds(bounds);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want `bounds.extend` inside the for loop. The way I see it, it's only taking a single marker's position.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that wth your code you get the position of the last marker and say to the map to fit to that. You do that with the

```
bounds.extend(marker.getPosition());              

    map.fitBounds(bounds);
```

if you want to fit to all the markers, then put

```
bounds.extend(m[i]);
```

in the for cycle after the marker.

A similar answer explains even better: [Google Maps v3 API Extend Bounds. Javascript How-To?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3610135/google-maps-v3-api-extend-bounds-javascript-how-to)